# Adding google analytics code on ajax calls

Tags: gtag.js

I have added google analytics code on my site. It's working fine.
I want to add it on a particular ajax call.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-220192-2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '--my--GTAG--Number');
</script>
```

How can I trigger that so that I can add it and see on backend that that a particular ajax call has been hit?